# How do you revoke all EXECUTE privileges for a user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to grant EXECUTE PROCEDURE privileges to a user for specific procedures, only for a period of time. After the time period, I want to remove **all** execute privileges from the user - but leave other privileges that have been granted, like SELECT or INSERT, intact.

How do you remove all execute privileges? This doesn't seem to work:

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE add_data TO user1;

-- time passes, now:

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE list_data TO user1;

-- time passes, now time to revoke:

REVOKE EXECUTE ON *.* FROM user1;

The result is that the user still has execute on add_data and list_data. REVOKE EXECUTE on *.* only appears to revoke something if the user was granted EXECUTE ON *.*, and even then it removes the *.* privilege but leaves the more specific grants.

Am I missing something? Do I have to keep track in a table of all privileges I grant users and revoke them one by one (seems crazy)?

I'm using MySQL 5.6.10 on AWS Aurora Serverless.

Comment: I figured it out and posted an answer below. I thought GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE, GRANT EXECUTE ON db.\*, and GRANT EXECUTE ON \*.\* were all versions of the same thing and would cumulate permissions as you issue them; it does not work that way at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in SQL to "revoke all EXECUTE grants from the user" without knowing all the grants you ever gave them. Instead, you need to modify three mysql tables directly (eek). Like this:

```
SET @user = 'myuser';
SET @host = '%';

-- remove all proc-level execute permissions
DELETE FROM mysql.procs_priv WHERE user=@user AND Host=@host AND Proc_priv = 'Execute';

-- remove all db-level execute permissions
UPDATE mysql.db SET Execute_priv = 'N' WHERE user=@user AND Host=@host;

-- remove user-level permission
UPDATE mysql.user SET execute_priv = 'N' WHERE user=@user AND Host=@host;

-- force engine to reload its cached permissions so they take effect now
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

In MySQL you can easily accidentally give someone permissions that you didn't intend to if you aren't aware that there are **three** simultaneous EXECUTE permission states for each user.

`GRANT/REVOKE EXECUTE ON *.*`, `GRANT/REVOKE EXECUTE ON mydb.*`, and `GRANT/REVOKE EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE nnn` create three independent static states that are **not** synchronized as you make permission changes.

MySQL uses three permissions tables to determine the EXECUTE permission: the user table, the db table, and the procs_priv table.

(1) `GRANT EXECUTE ON *.* TO user1;`

This statement sets a flag (execute_priv) in the **user** table. If the user has this flag on, they can execute any procedure or function in any database.

(2) `GRANT EXECUTE ON mydb.* TO user1;`

This statement sets a flag (Execute_priv) in the **db** table for that user/db combination. 
If the user has this flag on for a database, they can execute any procedure or function in that database.

(3) `GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE proc TO user1;`

This statement makes an entry in the **procs_priv** table authorizing the user to execute that specific procedure.

Before a function/stored procedure call, the engine looks to see if you have the user-level privilege. If so, it doesn't look any further and goes ahead and makes the call. Then it looks to see if you have the database-level privilege. Finally it looks to see if you have the procedure-specific privilege.

**If you misunderstand as I did and think your grant and revoke statements are adding/subtracting from a current permission state, it can lead to a big mistake.**

Example 1: `REVOKE EXECUTE ON *.* FROM user1` does **not** revoke all EXECUTE privileges from user1. It removes the user-level global EXECUTE privilege from user1 and leaves all other EXECUTE privileges (database level and procedure level) in place.

Example 2: `REVOKE EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE proc1 FROM user1` does **not** remove the ability of user1 to execute proc1. If only erases the specific procedure-level permission. If the user was previously given mydb.* or *.* execute privileges, those are still present after your REVOKE.